# Ansible: Get the name of a file created by a script in the format name-<date>.tar

Tags: backup, ansible

I've a script for backup on my host. It's creating a file, that is specified on it's output:

```
********************************************************************************
Configuration files backup successfully.
Backup file is put to /root/backup_201409111318.tar.
********************************************************************************
```

How can I copy that file to the ansible server, to be able to later restore it? Is there any way to parse the output of a shell/command task and then do a fetch over that file? Maybe using the script module?

It's important to note that I can not just "fetch" files from the server (instead of using the backup script) because the script is performing some additional tasks to create the backup.

Thanks in advance,
Ignacio.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by creating a wrapper for my script that only outputs the file name to stdout and then using that on ansible:

```
 - name: Send backup script
   copy: src={{ item }} dest=/tmp owner=root group=root mode=744
   with_items:
       - backup.sh
       - backup_wraper.sh

 - name: Exec the script
   command: /tmp/backup_wraper.sh
   register: backup_path

 - name: Get the file
   fetch: src=/root/{{ backup_path.stdout }} dest=/tmp/{{ backup_path.stdout }} flat=yes
```

Comment: Another option would have been to capture the output in a variable and pipe it to sed using the command module to get just the filename. Ansible also has a regex filter http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#other-useful-filters

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize [syncronize](http://docs.ansible.com/synchronize_module.html) module to accomplish this. You would use `delete=No` parameter to make sure if you keep multiple versions of your backups, they won't be deleted.
Additionally, you could register exit code if your backup script and run *syncronize* task only when there's a correct exit code.

```
# Synchronization of src on delegate host to dest on the current inventory host
synchronize: >
    src=some/relative/path dest=/some/absolute/path delete=No mode=pull
    delegate_to: backup.host
```